# Dream of omniscience

Tags: story, situation

Dave is having a dream. In his dream he is walking happily along a street when he comes to a mysterious door.

[image]

He tries to simply open the door, but it is locked. It is his dream and he can do whatever he imagines right? Wrong, this door **will not** open; he tries explosives, chainsaws, lockpicks, balefire, hyper beams, karate chops, and none of it works! The only thing he doesn't have the power to do in this dream is to get into that room!

Suddenly Dave hears a voice at the door, and sees an eye peeking through the keyhole. "Hello there, I am an omniscient wizard!", the woman at the door said. "If you are done trying to destroy my house then maybe I can let you in. All I ask you is to show me something you don't know, that I couldn't tell you."

Dave accepts her offer and **draws a shape** in the air and the Wizard lets him in immediately.

What shape did Dave draw?

Comment: This seems *way* too broad. :/

Comment: Balefire? lol That's a sturdy door.

Comment: You mustn't use balefire! Believe me, I know.

Comment: @dcfyj cuendillar clearly

Comment: @Andrey if anyone gets the puzzle correct the dark one will escape!!

Comment: [A more appropriate picture, maybe....](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQlZN.png "Nothing to see here, move along")

Comment: Feynman's answer to a similar puzzle was the shape of a crankshaft. If you haven't seen one you can't be told what it is. Sadly, this is not the answer because you have to know the shape to discover the answer.

Comment: This is indeed too broad; looking at the accepted answer makes it obvious that there exit so many other irrational numbers like *e*, *phi*, or other answers which suit fit.

Comment: The OP already accepted Circle / π as the answer. A better answer would have been ∞ - as in everything in existence (you don't know everything, and she can't tell you everything).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> [image: The final digit]
>  (What's the last digit of pi?  Dave doesn't know, and the wizard cannot tell him.)

OP Answer:

> My original idea was to have the answer as a perfect circle, when you draw a perfect circle you are drawing the diameter and circumference, and the relationship between them. Therefore you are drawing the true value of pi, that you do not know, which the wizard cannot tell you, because it would take an infinite amount of time to say. However I changed my mind because I think this answer fits slightly better. EDIT: It had to be in a dream because you cannot draw a **perfect** circle in the real world.

Comment: If the person is all knowing then they would know

Comment: But asking for the last digit of pi would be like asking what is the largest number? The question is ill-conceived because it asks about something that doesn't exist.

Comment: So so close but not quite the answer I was looking for hint the question says "draws a shape"

Comment: @Melkor that comment was in answer to his previous answer, not the current one :)

Comment: @Melkor added a similar answer myself which may be what you were looking for

Comment: @Melkor Soooo.... this was accepted, though OP commented it wasn't quite right.  Curious minds want to know - what was the intended solution?

Comment: @Melkor Re OP's edit: the wizard can just say $\pi$ (/paɪ/). That's like saying you cannot say $1/3$ because you must say infinite number of $3's$ after the decimal point.

Comment: @Ankoganit pi is the name. What you said is equivalant to somebody saying tell me your phone number, and you show them "phone number" written down.

Comment: @Melkor That's still correct, just not helpful enough.

Answer (score 6):

Is the shape required a:

> Klien bottle?
>
>  [image: Klien bottle]

Because:

> Klien bottles are 4-dimensional (like how Möbius strips are 3D) and so the wizard cannot know one - they don't exist in the 3D world (we don't have any time-changing objects that change like that because the conservation of energy would result in a nuclear explosion at the 'end' of the Klein bottle).

Answer (score 4):

Maybe he drew

> the key to the door.

The wizard accepts because

> Dave does not know where the key is, otherwise he would have used it to open the door.
>  The wizard (probably) knows where the key is, because it's her house. 
> She will only open the door if Dave answers her riddle. If she told him how to obtain the key, then he could open the door without solving the riddle - therefore she cannot tell him.

Comment: See [my previous answer](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/revisions/48118/1) :)

Comment: @Rubio It seemed like a decent guess.  I've changed my guess to avoid being accused of copying answers.

Comment: It's a paradox...

Comment: @Melkor It's a proof by contradiction, not a paradox. That's why the wizard cannot tell Dave this information.

Answer (score 4):

He drew a picture of what it's like to be conscious inside the wizard's house.

Because the wizard is an imagining of his own mind, it is not itself conscious and therefore cannot describe what that would be like. The drawer does not know the answer either, because he has not yet been in the room.

Answer (score 2):

Could it possibly be

> This particular door, broken?

In theory, it is

> An object that cannot be broken, even by Dave, who is otherwise locally omnipotent. It is possible that someone who is omniscient, and thus knows everything that is or could be, cannot know the unknowable that is this door, in a broken state.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going with the obvious(?)

> Nothing

Because

> There is nothing that Dave doesn't know,  that an omniscient wizard couldn't tell him.

Answer (score 1):

He drew a

> Circle (perfect)

And wrote/drew the symbol for underneath

> What is the last digit of the interior angle?

This is unanswerable because

> The interior angles are infinite

Comment: But what does "the interior angles" mean?

Comment: @randal'thor what do you mean?

Comment: What do *you* mean? How do you define the "interior angles" of a circle?

Comment: @randal'thor its the size of the angle between two sides, and seeing as a circle technically has inifinite sides, the angles are infinitely small

Comment: And how do you define "sides" of a circle? It doesn't have any straight sides, only tangents.

Comment: The same as a side for any shape. @randal'thor the sides of a circle are inifintely small

Comment: See [here](https://www.reference.com/math/many-sides-circle-a9188ad96242526d) or similar

Comment: The definition of sides for polygons **doesn't work** for circles. Circles don't have sides! What would it mean for sides to be "infinitely small" anyway?

Comment: From your link: "*According to the definition, a circle cannot have sides because it isn't made up of line segments that are connected by shared endpoints that form interior angles.*"

Comment: Another very close answer but not *quite* what I was looking for.

Comment: @randal'thor SL?